# Converting from one template instantiation to another

Tags: c++11, template-meta-programming

I have a fixed sized string class defined as follows:

```
template <typename const std::size_t max_size>
class fixed_string {
...
};
```

This class keeps a char buffer to hold max_size of characters.

I would like the ability to pass objects of this class to methods that take a template instantiation which has a lower value for max_size template parameter without any copying. So for example following method:

```
void foo(const fixed_string<50>& val) {
}
```

should be callable using a fixed_string<100>, so that following should work:

```
void bar() {
 fixed_string<100> s = "gg";
 foo(s); 
}
```

How could I do this?

Comment: How do you think this would work? You clearly have two different fixed size buffers. One of 100 elements and the other of 50.

Comment: Foo gets is a string with max size of 50 which is read only and if we make that passed object to point to the char buffer of the string with size of 100, it should work. This will not work if foo accepts a non const reference however.

Comment: But that would mean that inside the function you have a `fixed_string<50>` that is really pointing to a char buffer of `100` elements. And there goes your invariant that a `fixed_string<50>` stores up to a `50` chars buffer.

Comment: Yes I need to see if I this is possible. Having a single character in each class might now work because then they will not be in a continuous chunk of memory, which is needed to implement the method to return a c string without any coping. But that's a nice suggestion.. Will have that in mind.

Answer (score 1):

The first instinct would be to `reinterpret_cast` from larger to smaller `fixed_string`s assuming the compiler lays them out in a similar fashion, but this would be illegal due to the strict-aliasing rules of C++ (Objects may never be accessed by references or pointers of different types, except if one of them is `[signed|unsigned] char`)

You can solve this by creating a custom reference template which `fixed_string`s can be converted to implicitly:

```cpp
#include <type_traits>

template<std::size_t N>
struct fixed_string_ref {
    char *string; 
};

template<std::size_t N>
struct fixed_string_const_ref {
    const char *string; 
};

template<std::size_t N>
struct fixed_string {
    char string[N];

    template<std::size_t M, typename std::enable_if<(M < N), int>::type = 0>
    operator fixed_string_const_ref<M>() const {
        return fixed_string_const_ref<M> { string };
    }

    template<std::size_t M, typename std::enable_if<(M < N), int>::type = 0>
    operator fixed_string_ref<M>() {
        return fixed_string_ref<M> { string };
    }
};

void foo(fixed_string_const_ref<10>) {}

int main() {
    fixed_string<20> f;
    foo(f);
  //fixed_string<5> g;
  //foo(g);              <- cannot be converted to fixed_string_const_ref<10>
}
```

`fixed_string[_const]_ref` simply holds a pointer to the `fixed_string`'s data and can therefore be passed by value without copying the string. There need to be two such types, one const and one non-const, to retain const-correctness.

The `enable_if` part ensures that only references to smaller-or-equal `fixed_string`s can be created.

**Optional**: By adding two constructors to `fixed_string_const_ref`, ordinary string literals may also be passed as a fixed string reference.

```cpp
template<std::size_t N>
struct fixed_string_const_ref {
    const char *string;

    explicit fixed_string_const_ref(const char *s)
        : string(s) {}

    template<std::size_t M, typename std::enable_if<(M >= N), int>::type = 0>
    fixed_string_const_ref(const char (&s)[M])
        : string(s) {}
};

// ...

int main() {
    // ....
    foo("Hello World");
  //foo("Hello");        <- cannot be converted to fixed_string_const_ref<10>
}
```

By making the first one `explicit` and the second one restricted via `enable_if`, references can again only be created from string literals that are long enough.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe you can add a copy constructor to your class, like this:

```
template <int max_size>
struct fixed_string {
   template <int sz> fixed_string(const fixed_string<sz> &f) {}
};
```

Then you can pass `fixed_string<100>` to function getting `const fixed_string<50>&`, but:

1. It will create a new instance of `fixed_string<50>`. This may be not too bad once you do not copy the data. So in your class you can have, for instance, a static buffer and a reference to a buffer. By default the reference points to internal buffer, but can also reference a buffer of other instance.
2. Probably, still need to use `enable_if` to make sure the size is appropriate
3. Having implemented the buffer-reference separation, you make make the whole thing more implicit, and create a special type of constructor which will be distinguished from *regular* copy constructor (in which you, probably, want to accept smaller and not larger buffers)

Answer (score 0):

`fixed_string<50>` and `fixed_string<100>` are unrelated types, so that doesn't work by default.

One possibility would be to make `fixed_string<N>` inherit from `fixed_string<N-1>`, but that might impose unwanted constraints on your implementation.

You could make `foo` a function template and use `static_assert` or SFINAE to ensure you pass a string of the right size:

```
template <std::size_t Size>
void foo (const fixed_string<Size>& val) {
    static_assert(Size >= 50, "Size must be at least 50");
}
```

Comment: Unfortunately making foo a template will not work because it will introduce huge changes to our full code base. inheriting fixed_string<> from fixed_string<N-1> seem to be a good idea! Why do you think it will impose constraints on your implementation? Are you referring to the compile time allocated char buffer in the class?

Comment: @user3612009 Yes, I haven't fully thought how an implementation of that might look, but I suspect you would have issues with unnecessary buffers in base classes or needing to store one character in each class instance. Maybe I'm wrong and it all works fine though.

Answer (score 0):

First of all: Two different instances of a template are different types, totally unrelated. It is the same problem as giving a `float` and a `char*` to the same method which can't work at all.

Because your fixed size container type can have the same methods under the hood you can derive from a base class as an option.

```
template <typename const std::size_t max_size>
     class fixed_string: public fixed_string_base {...}
```

This base class then can hold all methods which interact with the content of the containers via virtual functions.

But this seems to be a design problem! Maybe as a hint:
If you decide in compile time the size of the container but the rest of the program must act in run time with different types you have no real benefit of the usage. Maybe your base class have methods like getSize() which are overridden in each template instance you have the same memory/time consuming cost result as with a runtime dynamic array size.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, yes I know these are two different types, and that why I had to post this question :) I considered having the base class, but want to avoid virtual functions due to performance reasons. As you say, one solution is to stick with well defined sizes in the entire code base so that this issue does not arise.. But I wanted to have some flexibility too, because I am going to introduce this sting class to an existing code base.

Comment: @user3612009 As you mention: You can not have both together! You can't have compile time constants and optimization if you need methods which must deal with run time sizes. Simply you have to pay the price somewhere :-)